# Modulo is not processing correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7

I cannot seem to make sure that the python modulo function is working properly, I have tried various numbers and cannot seem to get a correct division.

ISBN Number

```
print """
Welcome to the ISBN checker,

To use this program you will enter a 10 digit number to be converted to an International Standard Book Number

"""

ISBNNo = raw_input("please enter a ten digit number of choice") 


counter = 11 #Set the counter to 11 as we multiply by 11 first
acc = 0 #Set the accumulator to 0
```

Begin the loop, multiply each digit in the string by a decrimenting counter
We need to treat the number as a string to obtain each placement

```
for i in ISBNNo: 
    print str(i) + " * " + str(counter)
    acc = acc + (int(i) * counter) #cast value a integer and multiply by counter
    counter -= 1 #decrement counter
print "Total = " + str(acc)
```

Mod by 11 (divide and take remainder

```
acc = acc % 11
print "Mod by 11 = " + str(acc)
```

take it from 11

```
acc = 11 - acc
print "subtract the remainder from 9 = " + str(acc)
```

concatenate with string

```
ISBNNo = ISBNNo + str(acc)
print "ISBN Number including check digit is: " + ISBNNo
```

Comment: Can be you more specific than you are not getting "correct division"? What is the result and what are you expecting?

Comment: I was expecting it to divide by 11 then minus remainder by 11 e.g. 89 would leave us with 8 and a final number of 10 when taken away from 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct, except for some issues:

1) You're trying to compute the checksum (last digit) if the ISBN. This means that you should only take 9 digits into consideration:

```
ISBNNo = raw_input("please enter a ten digit number of choice") 
assert len(ISBNNo) == 10, "ten digit ISBN number is expected"
# ...
for i in ISBNNo[0:9]: # iterate only over positions 0..9 
    # ...
```

2) Also there should be a special case here:

```
ISBNNo = ISBNNo + str(acc)
print "ISBN Number including check digit is: " + ISBNNo
```

You're doing modulo-11, so acc can be equal to 10. ISBN mandates that "X" should be used as the last "digit" in this case, which could be written as:

```
ISBNNo = ISBNNo + (str(acc) if acc < 10 else 'X')
```

Here's the fixed code, with example [number from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number#ISBN-10_check_digit_calculation): http://ideone.com/DaWl6y

---

In response to comments

```
>>> 255 // 11               # Floor division (rounded down)
23
>>> 255 - (255//11)*11      # Remainder (manually)
2
>>> 255 % 11                # Remainder (operator %)
2
```

*(Note: I'm using `//` which stands for floor division. In Python 2, you could simply use `/` too because you're dividing integers. In Python 3, `/` is always true division and `//` is floor division.)*

Comment: is there a reason why you are teaching him assert? even for dummy code, using assert as a mean to check thing is still bad.

Comment: Assert is simple. I think it's OK here; brief validation is better than none at all.

Comment: I have rerun the program and I have just ensured that it is using the whole input as it stopped at 3 because it wasn't formatted as a string but mod still isn't working which is odd as it adds up fine  cod  http://ideone.com/SfRNeq     http://s21.postimg.org/fwfzi9x9j/printscreen.png

Comment: How is that wrong? Please indicate what results you get vs what you expected

Comment: I was expecting correct division then the ability to take a whole remainder and minus from 11 as almost a diviser as I used thin function in VBA and got that sort of division

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I got the program working and I will look for an opportunity to help someone else in programming.